# View.setEnabled(false) does not work quite right in android

Tags: view, android

I just found out View.setEnabled(false) does not work quite right in android, in the following ways:

1. Disable parent view does not automatically disable child views. This is inconvenient.
2. Though grayed in color, disabled views can still get focus and get keyboard input, make choice, etc. This is not right.
3. When getting keyboard input, DEL/BACK can only remove one key backward no matter how many you input. This behavior only shows in disabled EditText.
4. Radio label is grayed but radio button image is not grayed.

It seems like a bug. But how do I get a real DISABLE feature?

EDIT: forget to mention the first.

Comment: the code is too long. i may make a test code and post it later.

Comment: No need of code for his question, these problem are very common

Comment: oh, maybe that is one reason why android is not up to iOS quality just guess

Comment: @MichaelSM most of the time the problem is between the chair and the keyboard.

Comment: There are many good reasons not to disable children.  Because Android took one design decision versus one in iOS does not make either right or better.  Don't get me started on iOS quality problems!

Comment: Extend the parent class and override the setEnabled method.  Call the base method to control the parent then enumerate the children and set them accordingly.

Comment: Just because android does not allow disabling all children at once, does mean iOS is better :). There are lots benefit of this, you will slowly when you will give more time in android development

Comment: I am all for android camp:) I am just promoting better quality for android apps as to improve or revert perception received by general market.

Comment: @Sameer I absolutely disagree. I much prefer a method which does exactly what it says it does (after all, it's not called `setEnabledAndOnChildren()`) and use polymorphism to extend that behaviour.  *That's* good OOP.

Comment: @Jeremy, I don't have a chair to lean back, literally. Nowadays, some people prefer to work by standing, don't you hear about?

Comment: Everything does not exist has has two reason either they are bug (or Need to include in sdk i.e new upgrade) or its not good in general. @Simon so you should get the point why this is no available. These case arise to meet our requirement so we have to use some other way around

Comment: @MichaelSM Nice one ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursively setting all descendants is needed, otherwise RadioButtons in the layout will not get setEnabled because RadioButtons are grand-children not direct children, there is RadioGroup in between. I record my best solution so far here based on others' answer.

```
public static void setEnabledAll(View v, boolean enabled) {
    v.setEnabled(enabled);
    v.setFocusable(enabled);

    if(v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++)
            setEnabledAll(vg.getChildAt(i), enabled);
    }
}
```

Subclass is not working at this time. If I have:

```
public MyView class View {
    protected void setEnabled(boolean enabled, boolean setChildren){
        setEnabled(enabled);
        setFocusable(enabled);
        if(setChildren && this isinstanceof ViewGroup){
              for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.getChildCount() ; i++ )
                  //this line will have issue if it is not MyView                      
                  this.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(enabled, true); 
        }
    }
}
```

unless View itself has this overloaded setEnabled like this:

```
public class View {
    protected void setEnabled(boolean enabled, boolean setChildren){
        setEnabled(enabled);
        setFocusable(enabled);
        if(setChildren && this isinstanceof ViewGroup){
              for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.getChildCount() ; i++ )         
                  this.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(enabled, true); 
        }
    }
}
```

This solution will eliminate problems 1, 2, 3. Problem 4 can be solved by setting disabled style selector for RadioGroup - I am not sure why android has no default disabled style selector for RadioGroup. Maybe another point for Android enhancement. Android is very flexible in SDK design also means sometimes extra work needed.

Answer (score 2):

From memory, please excuse typos:

```
class ExtendedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{

    protected void setEnabled(boolean enabled, boolean setChildren){

        super.setEnabled(enabled);

        if(setChildren){
              for ( int idx = 0 ; idx < this.getChildCount() ; idx++ ) {
                  (View)(this.getChildAt(idx)).setEnabled(enabled);
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is "super.setEnabled(enabled);" good here? if for disable case, super.setEnabled(false) will disable its parent also which is often undesirable.

Comment: Nope.  Because this class extends LinearLayout, the super call is to the base class.  What you're saying is "do what you normally do, then do my stuff as well".  You are extending the method.  It will *not* disable the parent of the layout.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to update this [Michael SM' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224560/view-setenabledfalse-does-not-work-quite-right-in-android/19235037#19235037) with kotlin. Override for view will looks like:

```
override fun setEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled)
    children.forEach { it.isEnabled = enabled }
}
```

Call now is:

```
view.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

I dono't have answer to your all questions but i will try for `first` and `second`

- **1** Its absolutely fine to not disabling child on disabling of Parent. Consider a case where you want to click button of a layout but don't want to click outer area. Best example in Listrow, you have button which you want to click but does not want to click row.

  **Disabling all child at once**

  ```
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
  for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
  View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
  child.setEnabled(false);
   }
  ```
- **2** Its happend only for EditText but you can stop it also. And `view.setFocusable(false);` is the correct to stop view gaining focus

Comment: For number 1, if there is an option to disable children together if disabling parent, that will be convenient. for number 2, yes only EditText can accept keyboard input in disabled state, but other views besides EditText can also accept focus in disabled state. This is not right.

Comment: Yes there is way to disable all child. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Simon, both of your answers are helpful to me but I can only choose one answer so the earliest answer gets the point.

Comment: I made change according to your suggestion so that all children set "child.setEnable(false);" and "child.setFocusable(false);". The disable behavior goes as expected including EditText views, except it is even worse for radio buttons: they are not disabled at all, neither grayed nor preventing click/tap on them, also can be focusable. Prior to this change, radio button labels were grayed(but not radio button images), and not clickable but can be focusable.

Comment: No, its not fine at all. Disable must disable child views too. If its about clicks and focus, there are other methods setClickable and setFocusable.

Comment: See it carefully i disabling all child using for loop